# Regular expressions and preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using `preg_replace()` and I need some help. I've been trying to do this for some time and it's time to face facts: I am really bad with regular expressions. I'm not even sure what can and can't be done with them.

Lets say I want to change the string `dogs` to `cats` no matter how much white space is between them. how do I do it?

```
dogs -> cats
d o g s -> c a t s
```

I have tried:

```
preg_replace("/D\s*O\s*+G/", "cat", $string);
```

and the string comes back with all "d o g" unchanged.

Next question: Is it possible to ignore characters between letters and not just white space?

```
d.o g.s -> c.a t.s
dkgoijgkjhfkjhs -> ckgaijtkjhfkjhs
```

And finally, when it comes to whole words, I can never seem to get the function to work either.

```
display: none -> somestring
display    :    none -> somestring
```

Often times I just cause `$string` to return empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Case sensitivity (add an "i" flag after the final "/" to make it insensitive). However, it's often more efficient to either lower-case or upper-case the string to whatever is being checked-for, rather than checking for both (unless it's necessary).

Comment: Besides getting a better grasp of regex's, I just want to control posts on my website better so someone can't write S O M E E T H N I C S L U R effectively avoiding the censor. The posts here have been very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you're not allowing it to recognise `d` and `D` as the same thing. To do that, just put `i` after the last `/` as a modifier.

Your `\s` can be anything you want to allow - in this case, you might want `.` to allow all characters (except newlines, except except with the `s` modifier added).

So try something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/d(.*?)o(.*?)g/i","c$1a$2t",$string);
```

Note that this will mean that `DOG` becomes `cat`. If you want to keep cases, try this:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback("/(d)(.*?)(o)(.*?)(g)/i",function($m) {
    return
        ($m[1] == "d" ? "c" : "C")
        .$m[2]
        .($m[3] == "o" ? "a" : "A")
        .$m[4]
        .($m[5] == "g" ? "t" : "T");
},$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are case sensitive

You will have to use

```
preg_replace("/[Dd]\s*[Oo]\s*+[Gg]/", "cat", $string);
```

or use the case insensitve modifier

```
preg_replace("/D\s*O\s*+G/i", "cat", $string);
```

If you want to match with characters other then space your just need to change your \s references to something that matches the allowed characters for example:

```
preg_replace("/D\W*O\W*+G/i", "cat", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to ignore all characters:

```
$res = preg_replace('~d([^do]*+)o([^g]*+)g([^s]*+)s~i' , 'c$1a$2t$3s', $string);
```